# Preciso retornar em % o valor de quantos números são positivos, a quantia de zero e de números negativos, nesta ordem, porém meu código está errado

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

```
function maisMenos(valores){
  var qtd = valores.length;
  var neg = valores.filter(nr=> nr < 0).length;
  var pos = valores.filter(nr=> nr > 0).length;
  var zer = valores.filter(nr=> nr ==0).length;
  var calcNeg = neg / qtd;
  var calcPos = pos / qtd;
  var calcZer = zer / qtd;
  var resultado = [];
  var insere = resultado.push(calcPos, calcZer, calcNeg);
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Embora dê para simplificar algumas coisas, acho que a única coisa errada é que faltou multiplicar o `calcNeg`, o `calcPos` e o `calcZer` por 100 cada um para ficar certo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Se o enunciado está correto, está fazendo coisas demais e a ordem do que está verificando está errado, como acho ser fácil observar isto no código.

```js
function calculos(valores) {
    return [
      valores.filter(nr => nr < 0).length / valores.length * 100,
      valores.filter(nr => nr == 0).length / valores.length * 100,
      valores.filter(nr => nr > 0).length / valores.length * 100
    ];
}
console.log(calculos([-1, 0, 1, 0, 2, -2]));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FilterPercentual.js).

Se o enunciado está errado a pergunta é inválida.